# How do I serialize this list of names with xmlserializer?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Take this sample XML:

```
<Teaching StudyPoint="0" Description="xx" OtherDiscussionVideo="True" VideoAfterStudentItem="False">
    <Theme>Test 1</Theme>
    <SourceMaterial>Material 1</SourceMaterial>
    <Names>
        <Name Class="2">a</Name>
        <Name Class="3">b</Name>
        <Name Class="1">b</Name>
    </Names>
</Teaching>
```

So far, I have managed to create this class for serialization:

```
namespace OutlookCalIFConsole.MWBData
{
    public class Teaching
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public int StudyPoint
        {
            get => _StudyPoint; set => _StudyPoint = value;
        }
        private int _StudyPoint;

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Description
        {
            get => _Description; set => _Description = value;
        }
        private string _Description;

        [XmlAttribute]
        public bool OtherDiscussionVideo
        {
            get => _OtherDiscussionVideo; set => _OtherDiscussionVideo = value;
        }
        private bool _OtherDiscussionVideo;


        [XmlAttribute]
        public bool VideoAfterStudentItem
        {
            get => _VideoAfterStudentItem; set => _VideoAfterStudentItem = value;
        }
        private bool _VideoAfterStudentItem;

        public string Theme
        {
            get => _Theme; set => _Theme = value;
        }
        private string _Theme;

        public string SourceMaterial
        {
            get => _SourceMaterial; set => _SourceMaterial = value;
        }
        private string _SourceMaterial;

        public Teaching()
        {
            _OtherDiscussionVideo = false;
            _VideoAfterStudentItem = false;
            _StudyPoint = 0;
            _Description = "";
            _Theme = "";
            _SourceMaterial = "";
        }
    }
}
```

How do I serialize the list of `Name` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following inside `Teaching` class:

```
public class Teaching {
    [XmlArrayItem("Name")]
    public Name[] Names;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Turns out I did not need the `Class` attribute in the end. So a simple `string[]` did the trick. Thanks.